# Tricky Pass by Value and Pass by Reference Recursion Question

Tags: c++, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

The following is the code snippet from C++. The right answer is 6561, but i don't quite understand why. I totally understand how the recursion runs behind the scene, but i cannot tell why the result is totally different between pass &x (reference) and x (value) into the function. Would anyone help me out? I am sooooo confused...much appreciated!

My step-by-step understanding is that every recursion do the calculation of c = c - 1 and x = x + 1 and pass the value into the recursive fun(x, c) as opposed to the right answer, which is to keep the same copy for x, shown as the following:

f(5,5) = f(6,4) * 6

f(5,5) = f(6,4) * 6 =  f(7,3) * 6 * 7

f(5,5) = f(6,4) * 6 =  f(7,3) * 6 * 7  =  f(8,2) * 6 * 7 * 8

f(5,5) = f(6,4) * 6 =  f(7,3) * 6 * 7  =  f(8,2) * 6 * 7 * 8 =  f(9,1) * 6 * 7 * 8 * 9 = 1 * 6 * 7 * 8 * 9 = 3024

```
#include <iostream>
int f(int &x, int c) {
   c  = c - 1;
   if (c == 0) return 1;
   x = x + 1;
   return f(x, c) * x;
} 

int main(){

  int a = 5; 
  int b = 5; 

  std::cout<<"final result is " << f(a,b) << "\n";

return 0;

}
```

Comment: Please be more specific. What exactly do you not understand? If you execute the program by hand on paper, what result do you get and how does it differ from the correct result? Can you add that by-hand evaluation to the question? Do you understand what references in C++ are in the first place?

Comment: Thank you Walnut for your reply! Yes, I do understand what reference is defined in C++, mainly alias. I will edit the question and make it clearer. Please take a look at it a few minutes later. Much appreciated!

Comment: Try printing out x and c in each iteration to help you understand.

Comment: I believe it has to do with the value of x in return... (*x). When you pass by reference that value is going to be the last value of x when the functions start returning. Whereas it would be the value of each scoped x if it was passed by value. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: @ Eyal D yes, i've done so. Each recursion gives me x = 6, 7, 8, 9; however, the answer contradicts with what i got for each recursion. As the answer suggests, every x in the recursion should be equal to 9.

Comment: I'm not quite sure about [Evaluation order](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order) and splitted `return f(x, c) * x;` into `int ret = f(x, c); return ret * x;`. I added some print debugging, and now it should be obvious why `&x` makes a difference: [**Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e6c36324a58865cb)

Comment: @PSgold thank you for the insights. Yes i think your answer is head toward the right direction. But i don't understand why it keeps the very last value of x.. Shouldn't it take the deducted value in each recursion, just like it pass the value to each recursive fun().

Comment: _Shouldn't it take the deducted value in each recursion, just like it pass the value to each recursive fun()._ If you pass `x` by reference, there is only one storage of `x` for all calls. Hence, the side effects of `x = x + 1;` become visible when the recursion is "unwound".

Comment: Note that the result depends on the unspecified order of evaluation of the operands to `*`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
f(5,5) -> c = 4; a = x = 6
f(6,4) -> c = 3; a = x = 7
f(7,3) -> c = 2; a = x = 8
f(8,2) -> c = 1; a = x = 9
f(9,1) -> c = 0; return 1;

-----

f(8,2) returns 1 * x = 9
f(7,3) returns 9 * x = 9 * 9 = 81
f(6,4) returns 81 * x = 81 * 9 = 729
f(5,5) returns 729 * x = 729 * 9 = 6561
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

```
return f(x, c) * x;
```

as it is referans the value of x not same which going in `f(x,c)` and with the multiplicative one `*x`. the latter one changed after `f(x,c)` calls end.